# how convert string without format to dateTime in xquery

Tags: datetime, xquery

I have a transformation in OSB. In the response I receive a string large 40, that represents a date time, but with no specific format. I need to cast this value to dateTime.

For example:

```
<ns2:fechaHora>{
   fn-bea:dateTime-from-string-with-format('dd/MM/yyyy', $row/ns1:fechor)
}</ns2:fechaHora>
```

Actually I receive for example 01/12/2019, but in the future I will receive other formats, for example: 2019/12/01 or 12/01/2019, and others..

How can I format such a variety of string values and turn them into dataTime?

Comment: Can you show examples of the date strings you get? Otherwise it is really hard to give you any relevant advice.

Comment: If 12/01/2019 can represent either 12th January or 1st December then you clearly can't handle both of them without fiurther information. You're also likely to have difficulty parsing a date like "Quinquagesima Sunday 1549". Your problem is underspecified: you need to know what the possible input formats are, and how they are to be decoded.

Comment: Michael Kay, you are correct, it's imposible know that, is necessary define an input format, thanks for your help. Regards !!